# Need help regarding Playback functionality of Wowza Server

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, video-processing, wowza

**Scenario:**

We have developed our own software for Stream scheduling and we are using Wowza monthly paid services for broadcasting. We are creating a Playlist for scheduling VOD and Live Streams. We also doing recording of Live Streams. Now we have scenario where we have Playlist like below.

**Playlist for Day 1 of month.**

VOD 1   Playlist Start Time: 10:00 AM Duration: 1 hrs

VOD 2   Duration: 30 mins

Live Stream 1 Start Time is 11:30 AM and End Time is 02:00 PM. This is recurring daily Event and we are using Php crone job to handle this. (We are doing recording for this and recording is saved on Wowza content.)

VOD 3 Duration: 50 mins

VOD 4 Duration: 10 mins

Now we start broadcasting and first VOD 1 start broadcasting at 10:00 AM as per playlist schedule and then VOD 2 start broadcasting at 11:00 AM and then we start broadcast of
Live Stream. At the same time we are recording that. At 02:00 PM our Live broadcast end we start broadcasting VOD 4 and other items in list as per schedule.

Now on Day 2 we have same playlist and what we want that if somehow due to Technical snag or some other reason Live Stream (3rd item in playlist) is not available then Recently recorded content of Live stream get automatically start playing (i.e. Day 1 content which is available on Wowza server content folder.

**Need you help:**

So, I need a solution how to handle this? Need detailed solution what to change and where to change. I don’t have any development team.

I again request everybody to provide detailed solution this is something related to our Business and any delay will result in our Business Loss. Hope you understand.

Many Thanks,
vikram

Comment: There is no point in emphasizing the importance of this question for your business, all questions are important to someone here. Best if you develop a custom module, but if you don't have dev team you need to look for a freelancer.

Comment: Thanks I will arrange Java Developers but I am lost what to change where to change. Wowza provide me 3 files 

ModuleLoopUntilLive.java
ModuleStreamPublisher.java
ServerListenerStreamPublisher.java

We are trying t ounderstand there framework but still we lost somewhere. It will be great help if you put some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

[ModuleLoopUntilLive](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?468-How-to-loop-a-pre-roll-until-a-live-stream-starts-(ModuleLoopUntilLive)) and StreamPublisher modules also come as pre-compiled modules that you can add to your deployment without programming, but they do require additional configuration.

1. Download wse-plugin-streampublisher.zip from the Support Article for the pre-configured module.
2. Double click on the zip file to extract the contents. Copy the lib/wse-plugin-streampublisher.jar file from the package to the lib folder into your Wowza Streaming Engine installation in [install-dir]/lib directory.

You will want to set up something like LoopUntilLive so you can have the recording of Day 1 play until your live stream for Day 2 is available. Assuming you are providing adaptive bitrate, replace “mp4.sample.mp4” in the sample SMIL file with the name of your Day 1 VOD asset. You can set up a script to update the SMIL file with the name with the preceding day’s recording file name so that on any given day it will play the previous day's recording.

```
<smil>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <stream name="Stream1"></stream>

    <playlist name="pl1" playOnStream="Stream1" repeat="true" scheduled="2009-12-11 16:00:00">
        <video src="mp4:day1RecordedFileNameHere.mp4" start="0" length="20"/>
    </playlist>
</body>
```

For the developer who wants to further customize, the java source code files are available (which is what I believe you have and referenced).